# Is there any verses in the Quran where it says a man or woman should marry only after reaching puberty?

Tags: quran, reference-request

Is there any verse in the Quran where it says a man or woman should marry only after reaching puberty?

Comment: How is someone a man or a woman without reaching puberty?!

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/quranalyzeit.wordpress.com/2014/03/18/cii-vs-islam-does-the-quran-really-permit-child-marriage/amp/ This may help

Answer (score 1):

Qur'an [says](https://quran.com/4/6),

> " وَابْتَلُواْ الْيَتَامَى حَتَّى إِذَا بَلَغُواْ النِّكَاحَ فَإِنْ
>   ءَانَسْتُم مِّنْهُمْ رُشْدًا فَادْفَعُواْ إِلَيْهِمْ أَمْوَالَهُمْ"
>
> And test the orphans [in their abilities] until they reach
>   marriageable age. Then if you perceive in them sound judgment, release
>   their property to them. And do not consume it excessively and quickly,
>   [anticipating] that they will grow up. And whoever, [when acting as
>   guardian], is self-sufficient should refrain [from taking a fee]; and
>   whoever is poor - let him take according to what is acceptable. Then
>   when you release their property to them, bring witnesses upon them.
>   And sufficient is Allah as Accountant.

Here, the word  **بلوغ النّكاح**  is used which translates to "Mature enough to be married". That is, they must have matured; i.e. mentally developed.

Maturity period starts after puberty, but its time may vary from person to person. For example a person may have reached the age of puberty, at the same time as “age of maturity” other person may have not reached the “age of maturity” although  a few years had passed after puberty.

So, having attained maturity is compulsory for marriage besides having reached the puberty.
الله اعلم